# jQuery HeightMatch.js sets blank style attribute after AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read about issues with AJAX and matchHeight.js (https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height), and have tried the suggested solutions with no joy so far.

I have posted an issue on GitHub, but I was hoping SO could shed some light!

I'm using the `[data-mh]` method to run my height matches, so I'm not sure if this has any bearing on my issue.

So, I have elements with the `[data-mh]` attribute set with about 3 different groups running at one time. I'm AJAX-ing in more elements, and want to height match these new elements in the same way.

I have the following code at the moment, commented with where I think the issue is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-load-more', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var button = $(this);
var offset = $('.ajax-dump').find('.product-box').length/12;
var termID = button.data('id');
var taxonomy = button.data('taxonomy');
var postType = button.data('posttype');
var ajaxDump = $('.ajax-dump');

ajaxDump.addClass('preloader');
button.show().html('Loading...');

$.ajax({
    url: loadMoreProducts.ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'load_more_products',
        offset: offset, 
        termID: termID,
        taxonomy: taxonomy, 
        postType: postType,
    }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {

        var products = result.posts;
        var count = result.count;

        ajaxDump.append(products);
        moreProductsCallback();

        if( count < 12 ) { // there are no more products...
            $('.js-load-more').hide();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

function moreProductsCallback() {

    ajaxDump.removeClass('preloader').find('.page.hide').fadeIn(500, function() {

        $('.page').removeClass('hide');
        button.html('Load More Products'); 
        var newProducts = $('.ajax-dump').find('[data-mh]'); // this finds all the correct elements

        $.fn.matchHeight._maintainScroll = true;
        newProducts.matchHeight({ remove: true }); // this works, removes the height match from all elements
        $.fn.matchHeight._apply(newProducts); // this sets a blank style attribute

    });
}

});
```

I'm hoping I'm just going wrong somewhere, but I've been looking at this for a couple of days now, with no joy.

When the `$.fn.matchHeight._apply(newProducts);` runs, my `[data-mh]` elements do get an inline `style` attribute added, but no style is actually attached to the elements.